# linq subquery join and group by

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Hi is it possible to translate the below queries into linq ? ...
I am using entity frameworks core and tried to use the stored procedure but it seems like i have to create a model that applies to the metadata of the stored procedure. So i am trying to understand whether this kinda such query can be translated into linq so i don't have to create a separate db model.

```
    SELECT 
    Stock.stockID ProductID, 
    stockName ProductName, 
    categoryName ProductCategory, 
    typeName ProductType, 
    sizeName ProductSize, 
    currentQuantity CurrentQuantity, 
    standardQuantity QuantityPerBox, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),CONVERT(INT,Stock.price)) AvgUnitCost,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),CONVERT(INT,x.lastUnitCost)) LastOrderUnitCost,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATE,x.lastOrderDate)) LastOrderDate
FROM dbo.Stock
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT stockID,unitPrice lastUnitCost ,orderDate lastOrderDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY stockID ORDER BY orderDate DESC) rn FROM dbo.SalesOrder 
    JOIN dbo.SalesOrderDetail ON SalesOrderDetail.salesOrderID = SalesOrder.salesOrderID
WHERE customerID = @customerID AND salesStatus = 'S'
) x ON x.stockID = Stock.stockID AND rn = 1
LEFT JOIN dbo.StockCategory ON StockCategory.stockCategoryID = Stock.stockCategoryID
LEFT JOIN dbo.StockType ON StockType.stockTypeID = Stock.stockTypeID
LEFT JOIN dbo.StockSize ON StockSize.stockSizeID = Stock.stockSizeID
WHERE disStock = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything is possible. you just need to be careful with performance.

```
var query = 
    from stock in db.Stocks
    join x in (
      from grp in (
        from so in db.SalesOrders
        join sod in db.SalesOrderDetails on so.SalesOrderId equals sod.SalesOrderId
        where so.CustomerId == customerId && so.SalesStatus == "S"
        orderby so.OrderDate descending
        select new {
            sod.StockId, 
            LastUnitCost = sod.UnitPrice,
            LastOrderDate = so.OrderDate
        } into inner
        group inner by inner.StockId)
      select grp.Take(1)) on x.StockId equals stock.StockId into lastStockSales
    from x in lastStockSales.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join sc in db.StockCategories on stock.StockCatergotyId equals sc.StockCategoryId into scLeft
    from sc in scLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join st in db.StockTypes on stock.StockTypeId equals st.StockTypeId into stLeft
    from st in stLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join ss in db.StockSizes on stock.StockSizeId equals ss.StockSizeId into ssLeft
    from ss in ssLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where stock.DisStock == 0
    select new MyDTO {
      ProductId = stock.StockId,
      ProductName = stock.StockName,
      ProductType = st.TypeName,
      ProductSize = ss.SizeName,
      CurrentQuantity = stock.CurrentQuantity,
      QuantityPerBox = stock.StandardQuantity,
      AvgUnitCost = stock.Price,
      LastOrderUnitCost = x.LastUnitCost,
      LastOrderDate = x.LastOrderDate
    };
```

As you can see is easy to rewrite these queries, I had to change a little bit the logic on how to get the latest sales for a stock item since `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION...` is not supported from a LINQ perspective. Again, you would have to consider performance when rewriting queries.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow ..this really helps ! but considering performance.. is it a better practice to create separate model in the context which then can be used with the stored procedure ?  Problem i have is i am using database first approach and this means i have to create the table and reflect that in the model means this table in sql database just gets created for the purpose of making the model in the code...

Comment: I would say it depends on the amount of data you are talking about. You could do some performance testing to see if this LINQ query is close to the raw query. `ROW_NUMBER()...` might give you better performance, it might not. Do some tests and see the difference. My answer just shows you how from C# you can express rich queries. Your application will dictate what is the best approach. EF is a tool (a great one), but not the only one. You can decide to mix tools, and that is not a bad approach. I have done it many times to offer the best experience to the end user.

Comment: In terms of having to add another model to handle the result of the store proc, that would be the only solution you have at the current time. I hope better raw SQL support is added in the near future the same way EF 6 provides today with `Database.SqlQuery<T>(...)` method.

Comment: Thanks it really helped a lot.